# How to update array values when mutating Campaign in AdWords API

Tags: google-ads-api

I have trouble updating array values inside Campaign. For example I have this field:

```
'selectiveOptimization': {
    'conversionTypeIds': [
        111,
        222
    ],         
}
```

I can't find a way to replace that array, it is doing some sort of append operation internally instead of replace. If I pass `'conversionTypeIds': [333]` the result will be `[111, 222, 333]`

I tried passing null or empty array to reset it and it has no effect either.

My mutate operator for CampaignService:

```
operators = [{
    'operator': 'SET',
    'operand': {
        'id': <campaign_id>,
        'selectiveOptimization': {
            'conversionTypeIds': [
                333
            ]
        }         
    }
}]
```